# calling an API with a username and pass

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs, controller, resources

I'm trying to create an html page with AngularJS, where a user inputs a username and password and the controller calls an API to verify if they are correct. Here is the controller code, which doesn't work. Could you help me?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('SiteApp', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  return{
    $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};

    $scope.go = function() {
        //$scope.msg = 'clicked '+ $scope.user.username + ' ' + 
        //$scope.user.password;
        //alert("Testar entrada na função de go()");
        console.log($scope);
        $http.jsonp('http.//beta.cloogy.com:6969/api/1.0').
            data= {
              "User": user.username,
              "Password": user.password
            };
        .success(function (data) {
          $scope.$parent.image = data;
          return $location.path('/Index')
        });

        .error(function (data) {
           return $scope.msg="Erro, não foi feita validação correctamente!";
            {{msg}}
        });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: why do you want to pass passwords in url?

Comment: Because user and pass will be validate in that url, instead in html page. After that, i will need to receive a response token. So, the user write his username and password and they need to be validated in that url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a ***lot*** of javascript syntax errors in your code.  The following code is at the very least syntatically correct. Whether it does what you're trying to accomplish I don't know.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('SiteApp', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
  $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};

  $scope.go = function() {
    $http.jsonp('http.//beta.cloogy.com:6969/api/1.0', {
        data: {
          User: user.username,
          Password: user.password
        }
      })
      .success(function (data) {
        $scope.$parent.image = data;
        $location.path('/Index');
      })
      .error(function (data) {
        $scope.msg="Erro, não foi feita validação correctamente!";
      });
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am a novice yet :p

Comment: Your help it was very usefull but there is an error yet (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .) in the line 6,   $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};

I don't understand want is the problem.

Besides that, I have another error (Error: Argument 'LoginCtrl' is not a function, got undefined).

Sorry for bother you with that.

Comment: You don't need line #5 `return{`  or the 2nd to last line `}`.

Comment: I updated my answer with the full code (minus javascript syntax errors).

Comment: I'm sorry, this site is new for me and I didn't see. There is an error yet caused by an }, i'm trying to find it